# How do I position a text on top of a circle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have code to make a circle and I'd like to place text on top of it.

I'm using this for my example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/7341714/

```
    infoHeight = 200
    infoWidth = 200

    var compareSVG = d3.select(".info-container")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("class","comparison-svg")
                .attr("width", infoWidth)
                .attr("height", infoHeight);

    var circle = compareSVG.append("g")

    circle.append("circle")
    .attr("r", circleRadius(d.properties.contextvalue))
    .attr("cy", infoHeight/2)
    .attr("cx", infoWidth/2)
    .style("fill","grey")
    .style("stroke","black")
    .style("stroke-width","3px")

    circle.append("text")
    .text(d.properties.contextvalue)
    .style("display", "block")
    .style("y", infoHeight/2)
    .style("x", infoHeight/2)
    .style("color","red")
    .style("font-size","20px")
```

The circle works, but the text won't appear on top of it. Instead, it is in the top left corner of the SVG element. I've tried `position: absolute` along with `top` and `left` and it stays in the same corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3, the `attr` methods uses [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) internally, while `style` uses [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).

In an SVG `<text>` element, `x` and `y` are **attributes**. Therefore, change those `style()` methods for `attr()`. Also, get rid of that `.style("display", "block")`.

So, it should be:

```
circle.append("text")
    .text(d.properties.contextvalue)
    .attr("y", infoHeight/2)
    .attr("x", infoHeight/2)
    .style("color","red")
    .style("font-size","20px")
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
infoHeight = 200
infoWidth = 200

var compareSVG = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", infoWidth)
  .attr("height", infoHeight);

var circle = compareSVG.append("g")

circle.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 50)
  .attr("cy", infoHeight / 2)
  .attr("cx", infoWidth / 2)
  .style("fill", "lightgrey")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "3px")

circle.append("text")
  .text("Foo Bar Baz")
  .attr("y", infoHeight / 2)
  .attr("x", infoHeight / 2)
  .style("color", "red")
  .style("font-size", "20px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, pay attention to the position of the text: it's not entered (regarding the circle). If you want to center it, use `text-anchor` and `dominant-baseline`:

```js
infoHeight = 200
infoWidth = 200

var compareSVG = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", infoWidth)
  .attr("height", infoHeight);

var circle = compareSVG.append("g")

circle.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 50)
  .attr("cy", infoHeight / 2)
  .attr("cx", infoWidth / 2)
  .style("fill", "lightgrey")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", "3px")

circle.append("text")
  .text("Foo Bar Baz")
  .attr("y", infoHeight / 2)
  .attr("x", infoHeight / 2)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
  .style("color", "red")
  .style("font-size", "20px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's the difference between an attribute and a style? My rookie answer is that style refers to CSS and attributes refers to HTML.

Comment: @Cauder it's a bit more complicated than that. I added a first paragraph with some links, please have a look.